# SQL DECIMAL losing precision when SET with calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server I declare a decimal variable, then set it from an equation. The decimal variable loses precision. However, if I just select the equation, the precision is intact. How do I set the decimal variable without losing precision?

**SQL**:

```
DECLARE @_oDiscount decimal(10,2)

SET @_oDiscount = CAST(9.99 AS decimal(10,2)) * CAST(.5 AS float)

SELECT @_oDiscount AS DecimalVariable, CAST(9.99 AS decimal(10,2)) * CAST(.5 AS float) AS Equation
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
DecimalVariable   |   Equation
-------------------------------
5.00              |   4.995
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, **YOU'VE** defined the decimal to contain **only 2 digits after the comma**!

Therefore, the result of the calculation being 4.995, it will be rounded to 5.00.

If you would be using `DECIMAL(12,4)` instead, then there is **no loss** of precision!

```
DECLARE @_oDiscount decimal(10,4)

SET @_oDiscount = CAST(9.99 AS decimal(10,4)) * CAST(0.5 AS DECIMAL(10,4))

SELECT @_oDiscount
```

--> return 4.9950

Also: I would recommend against using `FLOAT` whenever possible!

And furthermore: there's really no need for all those casts..... just use

```
SET @_oDiscount = 9.99 * 0.5
```

and you'll get just the same results.

The `DECIMAL(p, s)` defines how precise the decimal value will be: `p` (precision) stands for the **total** number of digits, while `s` (scale) stands for the number of digits **after** the decimal point.